# Exception output in python

Tags: python

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        try:
            raise Exception("0")
        finally:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Does this code print 0 when you call fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 0)?

Comment: Have you tried to run it?

Answer (score 1):

It does not print `0` because another exception is raised in the `finally` block, replacing the original exception `Exception("0")`, so the outer `try-except` block only prints the latter exception.